# Bind enum to RadioButton TwoWay in WinUI3

Tags: c#, binding, winui-3

I want to bind an `enum` to some radio buttons in `WinUI3`. I have tried a couple of solutions used in `Wpf`, but none of them are operational in `WinUI3`.

Here is my latest try:

```
    // My actual enum
    public enum PPGSensorType
    {
        Reflective = 1,
        Transmission = 2
    }
```

```
    public class EnumToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            string parameterString = parameter as string;

            if (parameterString == null)
                return false;

            if (Enum.IsDefined(value.GetType(), value) == false)
                return false;

            object parameterValue = Enum.Parse(value.GetType(), parameterString);

            return parameterValue.Equals(value);
        }

        // TargetType is `Object` in ConvertBack. I don't know what to do about it.
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            string parameterString = parameter as string;

            if (parameterString == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Parameter should be passed for parsing the enum value.");

            return Enum.Parse(targetType, parameterString);
        }
    }
```

As I mentioned above, `TargetType` is `Object` in convert back so it can't convert back the value correctly.

```
<RadioButtons>
    <RadioButton Margin="20 0 0 0" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=addDeviceDialog, Path=ViewModel.Device.PPGSensorType, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Reflective,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="Reflective"/>
    <RadioButton Margin="20 0 0 0" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=addDeviceDialog, Path=ViewModel.Device.PPGSensorType, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Transmission, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="Transmission"/>
</RadioButtons>
```

I have tried a new way of telling the exact value of Converter's parameter using static resources. In `app.xaml` I added the following resources:

```
<presentation:PPGSensorType x:Key="ReflectivePPGSensor">Reflective</presentation:PPGSensorType>
<presentation:PPGSensorType x:Key="TransmissionPPGSensor">Transmission</presentation:PPGSensorType>
```

```
<RadioButtons>
    <RadioButton Margin="20 0 0 0" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=addDeviceDialog, Path=ViewModel.Device.PPGSensorType, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource ReflectivePPGSensor},Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="Reflective"/>
    <RadioButton Margin="20 0 0 0" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=addDeviceDialog, Path=ViewModel.Device.PPGSensorType, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource TransmissionPPGSensor}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="Transmission"/>
</RadioButtons>
```

It didn't work, either.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<PPGSensorType> _pPGSensorTypes = Enum.GetValues<PPGSensorType>().ToList();

    [ObservableProperty]
    private PPGSensorType? _selectedPPGSensorType = PPGSensorType.Reflective;

    partial void OnSelectedPPGSensorTypeChanged(PPGSensorType? oldValue, PPGSensorType? newValue)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"SelectedPPGSensorType changed from {oldValue} to {newValue}");
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<RadioButtons
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.PPGSensorTypes, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedPPGSensorType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I'm using the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty) NuGet package for the MVVM design.

Comment: sry for late answer I was rly busy, I have tried your code but it doesn't works. When I switch between options I throws into `Object reference doesn't set to an instance of an object`. I think there is an issue with `TwoWay` binding of `SelectedItem` property in `RadioButtons`. I forced to write separated `Converters` for each kind of `enum`. I will be very appreciated to find a better solution.
tnx bro 

Comment: This code works on my side. The only way that I can reproduce that exception is if I make `private PPGSensorType?` not nullable. Can you make sure that you added the `?`?

Comment: BTW, I'm making it `nullable` due to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3268). It should be fixed in the future.

Comment: I made it `nullable` but it doesn't works.

Comment: I actually created a sample app for this and it works. Are you having the same error about "Object reference..."?

Comment: Yea, I will try a cleaner code to find the reason. My project is getting huge.